# How to change the index name of array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, arraylist

I have a multidimensional array,

I'm recursively changing values of array with I need.

It is working for keys which are not array.

But not for keys which are array.

How can I change value of one to test like "one" => "test",

```
$arr = array(
      'one' => array(
            array('something' => 'value'),
            array('something2' => 'value2'),
            'another' => 'anothervalue'
            ),
      'two' =>  array(
            array('something' => 'value'),
            array('something2' => 'value2'),
            'another' => 'anothervalue'
            )
       );

function update_something(&$item, $key)
{
    if($key == 'one')
        $item = 'test';
}

array_walk_recursive($arr, 'update_something');
```

EXPECTED ARRAY STRUCTURE IS

```
array(
          'one' => 'test',
          'two' =>  array(
                array('something' => 'value'),
                array('something2' => 'value2'),
                'another' => 'anothervalue'
                )
           );
```

UPDATE2

```
$html_structure = array(
    array(
        'tag' => 'div',
        'class' => 'lines',
        array(
            'tag' => 'div',
            'one' => array(
                'tag' => 'div',
                 array(
                    'tag' => 'span',
                    'style' => 'margin:10px; padding:10px',
                    'key' => 'title',
                ),
                'key' => 'subject',
            )
        )
    )
);
```

UPDATE3

```
$array = array(
    array(
        'tag' => 'div',
        'class' => 'lines',
        array(
            'tag' => 'div',
            'repeat' => array(
                'tag' => 'div',
                 array(
                    'tag' => 'span',
                    'style' => 'margin:10px; padding:10px',
                    'key' => 'title',
                ),
                'key' => 'subject',
            )
        )
    )
);



function update_recursively($array, $key = '', $value = array()) {
    //print_r($array); print_r($value);
    foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
        if ($k === $key){ 
            $array[$k] = $value;
        }
        elseif (is_array($v))
            $array[$k] = update_recursively($v);
    }
    return $array;
}

print_r(update_recursively($array, 'repeat', array('d' => 'a')));
```

Comment: @Marcus this is your function could you solve this also?

Comment: You mention your expected array structure, but what is the structure you are getting?

Comment: @StephenTG this function fails. It returns what I give to it.

Comment: Looking at the documentation it quite clearly states "Any key that holds an array will not be passed to the function.", so in `update_something` $key will never be set to 'one'. That's simply the behaviour of array_walk_recursive.

Comment: @SilverSnake is it possible with another function?

Comment: @DenizPorsuk I'm looking through the docs, but I can't see a built-in function that does exactly what you want. It should be fairly straight forward to write your own recursive function that does it though unless your array is really big it should be fairly safe.

Comment: @SilverSnake  http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php#112604 is finding the key but how can I update it?

Comment: @DenizPorsuk Posted an example code snippet that should do what you are asking for. Sometimes there's no built in function that does exactly what you want. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you array isn't too large, something like this would work:

```
function update_recursively($array) {
    foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
        if ($k === 'one')
            $array[$k] = 'test';
        elseif (is_array($v))
            $array[$k] = update_recursively($v);
    }

    return $array;
}

$updated_arr = update_recurisvely($arr);
```

But you need to be a bit careful if it's really big as it can get slow and memory intensive. Note that it won't update your old array, like array_walk_recursive would, it will return an updated version instead.

*** UPDATE ***

Version that handles the Update3 scenario where we specify key to look for and value to replace it with.

```
function update_recursively($array, $key = '', $value = array()) {
    foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
        if ($k === $key)
            $array[$k] = $value;
        elseif (is_array($v))
            $array[$k] = update_recursively($v, $key, $value);
    }
    return $array;
}
```

Comment: This works pretty good. But I could not run it for UPDATE2 what could be problem?

Comment: @DenizPorsuk The issue was you had arrays without any keys, and 0 == 'one', I updated the code so that the first IF uses === instead, that should solve the issue with your UPDATE2.

Comment: SilverSnake you saved my day, but what ever I do, I could not run UPDATE3 what could it be problem?

Comment: @DenizPorsuk You updated the update_recursively() to take a key and a value, the line inside the elseif, that calls itself again, needs to have the $key and $value passed along as well. When it recurses in your code it stops looking for "repeat" and starts looking for "" (the default value). Change `$array[$k] = update_recursively($v);` into `$array[$k] = update_recursively($v, $key, $value);` and you should be good!

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
function update_something(&$item, $key) {
    if($key == 'one') {
        array_splice($item,0,'test');
    }
}
```

Comment: Gerard Do you have alternative?